# Why unexpected attached files are loaded in all mailings by default?

Tags: civimail, issues

We upgrade recently from 4.5.8 to 4.6.6 on four of our CiviCRM instances.

In one of the instances ocurrs something very strange and compromising. When we create a new mailing, in the attachment tab appears one/two random files uploaded previously to event custom fields.

However if we try to delete the attached file/s we get the following error:

> "Failed to run permission check: Unrecognized target entity table
>   (civicrm_participant)"

Why they appear if they have no connection with the mailings?

**Edit: Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: So we can start looking, how it is stored in the database attachments of a mailing?

Comment: Are you selecting a template when creating the mailing? Perhaps the template is defined to include attachments?

Comment: No, this happens even before selecting the template.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what's happening.  Could you please include a screenshot?

Comment: A related issue and a related bug report? http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4929/after-upgrading-to-4-6-7-civimail-fails-to-send-mail https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17085?jql=text%20~%20%22Failed%20to%20run%20permission%20check%3A%20Unrecognized%20target%20entity%20table%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found a workaround solution. It seems that is a bug in [Attachment.php](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/Attachment.php) API file.

**Original code**

```
315: foreach ($entityFile as $key => $value) {
316:   $select->where('cef.!field = @value', array(
317:     '!field' => $key,
```

**Workaround solution**

```
315: foreach ($entityFile as $key => $value) {
316:   $select->where('cef.!field'.$key.' = @value', array(
317:     '!field'.$key => $key,
```

Seems that if there is more than one `$entityFile` element, then `where` clause is generated wrongly.

Comment: So [where()](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/SQL/Select.php#L239) currently tries to dedupe redundant clauses by using `->wheres[$expr]`, and it erroneously treats two clauses ("cef.entity_table == 'foo'" and "cef.entity_id=123") as duplicates. The dedupe key should prob be post-interpolation rather than pre-interpolation.

Comment: Well, I like this patch better than the others -- it seems closer to the root cause. I've drafted a similar/alternative which I think gets at the cause https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6644 . Could you see if it fixes the problem for you?

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found the cause. Check out bug [CRM-16544](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16544), it matches your problem exactly (except theirs was Grant and yours is Event). I think we can fix this by adding `civicrm_event` to the array on line 210 of [Container.php](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/f85b80630e8324121dcdef2d7aacd432946b541f/Civi/Core/Container.php), but I'm not familiar enough with the Symfony stuff to be sure. I think your best bet is to file a bug.

Comment: Thanks, Nicholai! It really looks like the problem we have. However, adding `civicrm_event` to the array on line 210 of [Container.php](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/f85b80630e8324121dcdef2d7aacd432946b541f/Civi/Core/Container.php) seems it's not enough. We try also without luck with `civicrm_participant` and `civicrm_value_inscripci__14` that is the entity table of the custom file field in question.