# After upgrading to 4.6.7 Civimail fails to send mail

Tags: civimail, upgrade

The error message reads:

> Failed to run permission check: Unrecognized target entity table (civicrm_note)

Comment: do you find anything in the log file or the console output ?

Comment: No errors logged, but I manually examined this. The issue is the attachment.

Error is in Civi/API/Subscriber/DynamicFKAuthorization.php line 210.

Because:

public function getDelegatedEntityName

in that file, 'civicrm_note' is not in $this->allowedDelegates.

If I add 'civicrm_note' to that array in Civi/Core/Container.php line 211 (the constructor), then I get a different error:

Authorization failed on (Note,547)

which appears to be coming from line 236 of DynamicFKAuthorization.php.

Further debugging appears to require more in-depth knowledge of this code.

Comment: (1) What was the previous version which was working? (Interested to know if, eg, this is your first mailing on 4.6.x.) (2) When exactly does that error appear? After saving a draft? After scheduling/submitting the mailing? When executing the cron job?

Comment: Previous version was 4.5.6. Error occurs when trying to send a test email to one address

Comment: Same. I've also found that after triggering a mail out (via scheduled cron or testing), the server generates 80+ PHP connections and MySQL connections which are in sleep mode. The whole server goes offline, until MySQL is restarted. The mail out does go out though. <pre>
Aug 27 11:34:40 [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/clientusername/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(364): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/clientusername/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Form/Optout.php(55): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("There was an error in yo

Comment: Seems that we have a related problem. You can see here for our report http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4507/why-unexpected-attached-files-are-loaded-in-all-mailings-by-default

Answer (score 2):

As Francesc pointed out, the symptoms sounds very similar to a contemporaneous question -- [Why unexpected attached files are loaded in all mailings by default?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4507/why-unexpected-attached-files-are-loaded-in-all-mailings-by-default)

That was patched with https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6644 and released as part of 4.6.9.